# Evaluation the Elsasser function:$\text E(y,u)=\int_{-\frac12}^\frac12e^{\frac{2\pi uy\sinh(2\pi y )}{\cos(2\pi x)-\cosh(2\pi y)}}dx$ from MathWorld

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions, trigonometric-integrals

Here is another uncommon special function which is officially recognized inspired by:

> [Series Representation of the Glasser function: $$\text G(x)\mathop=\limits^\text{def} \int_0^x \sin(t\sin(t))dt\sim2\sqrt{\frac x\pi}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4290500/series-representation-of-the-glasser-function-text-gx-mathop-limits-text)

This time we would like to evaluate the [**Elsasser function**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ElsasserFunction.html) which I cannot find any primary source for $$\text E(y,u)\mathop=^\text{def}\int_{-\frac12}^\frac12 e^{\frac{2\pi uy\sinh(2\pi y)}{\cos(2\pi x)-\cosh(2\pi y)}}dx$$ Here is an [**interactive graph**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1ne7u10as7) of the function. I was able to get the following series representation using software and substitution of variables where appears the [Gauss Hypergeometric function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/): $$\text E(y,u)=\int_{-\frac12}^\frac12 e^{\frac{2\pi uy\sinh(2\pi y)}{\cos(2\pi x)-\cosh(2\pi y)}}dx= \int_{-\frac12}^\frac12 e^{\frac{a}{\cos(2\pi x)-b}}dx=\int_{-\frac12}^\frac12 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^n}{n!}(\cos(2\pi x)-b)^{-n}dx\ne \frac{i}{\sqrt{\pi (b^2+1)}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a^n\color{red}{(-n)!}}{n!\left(\frac12-n\right)!}\left((-1)^{1-n}(1+b)^{1-n}\,_2\text F_1\left(\frac12,1-n,\frac32-n,\frac{b+1}{b-1}\right)+(1-b)^{1-n} \,_2\text F_1\left(\frac12,1-n,\frac32-n,\frac{b+1}{b-1}\right)\right)$$

The 4th step can be evaluated using the [Appell $\text F_1$ function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/AppellF1/) and then plug in the bounds to get the hypergeometric functions.

The problem of $\cos(2\pi x)$ in the denominator creates the $(-n)!$ in the expansion and therefore in the integral. Another idea is to use one of [many other expansions](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Exp/06/) for $e^y$.

How can we find a series representation for the Elsasser function as seen in Wolfram Mathworld? We can use it to put complicated sums into closed Elsasser form.

The sum representation should have a single sum with closed form coefficients, so no nth derivatives please. You can also have 2 infinite series if really needed. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transforming the integral as
\begin{align}
 \operatorname E(y,u)&=\int_{-\frac12}^\frac12 \exp\left( \frac{2\pi uy\sinh(2\pi y)}{\cos(2\pi x)-\cosh(2\pi y)} \right)\,dx\\
 &=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \exp\left( \frac{\alpha}{\beta\cos t-1} \right)\,dt\\
 &=\frac{e^{-\alpha}}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \exp\left( \frac{\alpha \beta\cos t}{\beta\cos t-1} \right)\,dt
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
 \alpha&=2\pi uy\tanh( 2\pi y)\\
\beta&=\frac{1}{\cosh 2\pi y},
\end{align}
we can use the [generating function of the Laguerre polynomials](https://dlmf.nist.gov/18.12.E13)
\begin{equation}
 (1-z)^{-1}\exp\left(\frac{xz}{z-1}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}L_{n}\left(x\right)z^{n}
\end{equation}
valid for $|z|<1$. Here, taking $x=\alpha,z=\beta\cos t$, we have ($|\beta\cos t|<1$)
\begin{equation}
 \exp\left( \frac{\alpha \beta\cos t}{\beta\cos t-1} \right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}L_{n}\left(\alpha\right)\beta^{n}(1-\beta\cos t)\cos^nt
\end{equation}
Then by changing the order of integration and summation, one obtains
\begin{align}
 \operatorname E(y,u)&=\frac{e^{-\alpha}}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}L_{n}\left(\alpha\right)\beta^{n}\int_0^\pi (1-\beta\cos t)\cos^nt\,dt\\
 &=\frac{e^{-\alpha}}{\pi}\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}L_{n}\left(\alpha\right)\beta^{n}\int_0^\pi \cos^nt\,dt-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}L_{n}\left(\alpha\right)\beta^{n+1}\int_0^\pi \cos^{n+1}t\,dt\right]
\end{align}
For $p=0,1,2,\cdots$, the trigonometrics integrals
\begin{equation}
 \int_0^\pi\cos^pt\,dt=\begin{cases}
                        0&\text{ if }n=2p+1\\
                        \pi\frac{(2p-1)!!}{(2p)!!}&\text{ if }n=2p
                       \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Denoting
\begin{equation}
 a_p=\frac{(2p-1)!!}{(2p)!!}=2^{-2p}\binom{2p}{p}
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
 \operatorname E(y,u)&=e^{-\alpha}\left[\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}L_{2p}\left(\alpha\right)\beta^{2p}a_p-\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}L_{2p+1}\left(\alpha\right)\beta^{2p+2}a_{p+1}\right]
\end{align}
Finally,
\begin{equation}
 \operatorname E(y,u)=e^{-\alpha}\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\beta^{2p}\left[\frac{(2p-1)!!}{(2p)!!}L_{2p}\left(\alpha\right)-\frac{(2p+1)!!}{(2p+2)!!}\beta^2L_{2p+1}\left(\alpha\right)\right]
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
 \operatorname E(y,u)=e^{-\alpha}\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\binom{2p}{p}\left(\frac{\beta}{2}  \right)^{2p}\left[L_{2p}\left(\alpha\right)-\frac{2p+1}{2(p+1)}\beta^2L_{2p+1}\left(\alpha\right)\right]
\end{equation}
which seems to be numerically correct.

---

Edit: A Laplace transform method

Alternatively, one can use a Laplace transform method. From the expression
\begin{equation}
 \operatorname E(y,u)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \exp\left( \frac{\alpha}{\beta\cos t-1} \right)\,dt
\end{equation}
taking the Laplace transform wrt $\alpha$ under the integral leads to
\begin{equation}
 \mathcal{L}\left[\operatorname E,\alpha\to p\right]=\frac1\pi\int_0^\pi\frac{\beta\cos t}{p\beta\cos t-p-1}\,dt
\end{equation}
with $p>0$, and thus
\begin{equation}
 \mathcal{L}\left[\operatorname E,\alpha\to p\right]=\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{p\sqrt{(p+1)^2}-\beta^2p^2}
\end{equation}
The inverse transform can be expressed as
\begin{equation}
 \operatorname E(y,u)=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}\int_0^\alpha I_0\left( \frac{\beta s}{1-\beta^2} \right)e^{-\frac{s}{1-\beta^2}}\,ds
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
 \operatorname E(y,u)=1-\sqrt{1-\beta^2}\int_0^{\frac{\alpha}{1-\beta^2}} I_0\left(\beta s  \right)e^{-s}\,ds
\end{equation}
$I_0(.)$ is a modified Bessel function. From the [multiplication theorem](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.44.E1)
\begin{equation}
 I_{\nu}\left(\lambda z\right)=\lambda^{\nu}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}%
\frac{(\lambda^{2}-1)^{k}(\frac{1}{2}z)^{k}}{k!}I_{\nu+ k}\left(z%
\right),
\end{equation}
with$\nu=0$
\begin{align}
 \operatorname E(y,u)&=1-\sqrt{1-\beta^2}\int_0^{\frac{\alpha}{1-\beta^2}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(\beta^2-1)^k}{2^{k}k!}s^kI_k(s)e^{-s}\,ds\\
 &=1-\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{(1-\beta^2)^{k+1/2}}{2^{k}k!}\int_0^{\frac{\alpha}{1-\beta^2}}s^kI_k(s)e^{-s}\,ds
\end{align}
From the tabulated integral ([DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.43.E3)
\begin{equation}
 \int e^{\pm z}z^{\nu}I_{\nu}\left(z\right)\mathrm{d}z=\frac{e^{\pm z
}z^{\nu+1}}{2\nu+1}\left(I_{\nu}\left(z\right)\mp I_{\nu+1}
\left(z\right)\right)
\end{equation}
we obtain
\begin{equation}
 \operatorname E(y,u)=1-\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{(1-\beta^2)^{k+1/2}}{2^{k}k!}
 \frac{e^{- \frac{\alpha}{1-\beta^2}
}\left( \frac{\alpha}{1-\beta^2} \right)^{k+1}}{2k+1}\left(I_{k}\left(\frac{\alpha}{1-\beta^2}\right)+ I_{k+1}
\left(\frac{\alpha}{1-\beta^2}\right)\right)
\end{equation}
with $\gamma=\frac{\alpha}{1-\beta^2}=2\pi uy\coth2\pi y$,
\begin{equation}
  \operatorname E(y,u)=1-2\pi uy\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2^{k}k!}
 \frac{(2\pi uy\tanh(2\pi y))^{k}}{2k+1}\left(I_{k}\left(\gamma\right)+ I_{k+1}
\left(\gamma\right)\right)e^{- \gamma
}
\end{equation}
which seems numerically valid.

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the answer. You will probably win the bounty, but to take advantage of the bounty, I will wait until the grace period appears. Are there any apparent applications or simplifications for the sum?

Comment: $+1$ Nice. Good job.

Comment: Thanks @FelixMarin . I can't see new developments for these series (except in terms of incomplete gamma function by developping the Bessel function in $\int I_0(\beta s)\exp(-s)\,ds$)

Comment: @PaulEnta Good job. You have given 2 useful series representations with backup. You more than deserve the bounty and accept. Consider it a christmas gift.

Comment: Thanks to Santa aka @TymaGaidash!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Paul Enta’s answer here is a new decomposition formula for the [Kampé de Fériet function](https://functions.wolfram.com/Notations/5/) found on Wolfram Mathworld among other sources with this photo:

[image]

Using the Bessel Sum Representation:

> $$\begin{equation}
>   \operatorname E(y,u)=1-2\pi uy\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2^{k}k!}
>  \frac{(2\pi uy\tanh(2\pi y))^{k}}{2k+1}\left(I_{k}\left(\gamma\right)+ I_{k+1}
> \left(\gamma\right)\right)e^{- \gamma
> }, \gamma=2\pi uy\coth2\pi y
> \end{equation} $$

Remember that $\alpha=2\pi uy\tanh( 2\pi y)$ and use the [Bessel function definition](https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselI/02/) and [Pochhammer symbol](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html):

$$\frac{e^\gamma(1-\text E(y,u))}{2\pi uy}= \sum_{m,n\ge0}\left(-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)^m \frac{\left(\frac12\right)_m}{\left(\frac32\right)_m \Gamma(n+m+1)n!}\left(\frac \gamma 2\right)^{2n+m} +\sum_{m,n\ge0}\left(-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)^m \frac{\left(\frac12\right)_m}{\left(\frac32\right)_m \Gamma(n+m+2)n!}\left(\frac \gamma 2\right)^{2n+m+1}$$

With the Kampé de Fériet function defined above as:

$$\text F^{p,r,u}_{q,s,v}\left(^{a_1,…,a_p;c_1,…,c_r;f_1,…,f_u}_{b_1,…,b_q;d_1,…,d_s;g_1,…,g_v}\ x,y\right)\mathop=^\text{def}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\prod\limits_{j=1}^p(a_j)_{m+n} \prod\limits_{j=1}^r(c_j)_m \prod\limits_{j=1}^u (f_j)_n x^my^n}{\prod\limits_{j=1}^q (b_j)_{m+n} \prod\limits_{j=1}^s(d_j)_m \prod\limits_{j=1}^v(g_j)_n m!n!}$$

Therefore:

$$\frac{e^\gamma(1-\text E(y,u))}{2\pi uy} =\text F^{0,1,0}_{1,1,0}\left(^{\ \ ;\frac 12;}_{1;\frac 32;}\ \frac{\gamma \alpha}{4},\frac{\gamma ^2}4\right)+\frac \gamma 2 \text F^{0,1,0}_{1,1,0}\left(^{\ \ ;\frac 12;}_{2;\frac 32;}\ \frac{\gamma \alpha}{4},\frac{\gamma ^2}4\right) $$

and:

$$\text E(y,u)=1-\frac{2\pi y}{e^{2\pi uy\coth(2\pi y)}}\left[\text F^{0,1,0}_{1,1,0}\left(^{\ \ ;\frac 12;}_{1;\frac 32;}\ -(\pi uy)^2,(\pi uy \coth(2\pi y))^2\right)+\pi uy\coth(2\pi y) \text F^{0,1,0}_{1,1,0}\left(^{\ \ ;\frac 12;}_{2;\frac 32;}\ -(\pi uy)^2,(\pi uy \coth(2\pi y))^2\right)\right]$$

Unfortunately, $\text F^{0,1,0}_{1,1,0}$ seems to have no [Horn function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_function) form to simplify the already simple Kampé de Fériet representation. Please correct me and give me feedback!