# Solving $xy’’’+(1-m)y’’+2y=0,y=y(x)$ to prove hypergeometric representation of Abramowitz function from NIST.gov

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals, recreational-mathematics, special-functions, closed-form

**Intro**:

I was looking for a fresh new problem to solve and was inspired by

> [Evaluation the Elsasser function:$$\text E(y,u)=\int_{-\frac12}^\frac12e^{\frac{2\pi uy\sinh(2\pi y )}{\cos(2\pi x)-\cosh(2\pi y)}}dx$$ from MathWorld](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4291890/evaluation-the-elsasser-function-text-ey-u-int-frac12-frac12e-frac2)

The goal function is the [**Abramowitz function**](https://itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman2/auxillar/abram.htm) found in the [NIST catalogue of library functions](https://itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman2/ch6/homepage.htm). Here is an [interactive graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nzgq9hjhsn) of the function. Maybe the Abramowitz function appears in [Abramowitz and Stegun](https://books.google.com/books/about/Handbook_of_Mathematical_Functions_with.html?id=ZboM5tOFWtsC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&gboemv=1)? The function is also standardized like all of the functions in the [NIST DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/):

$$\text f_m(x)\mathop=^\text{def}\int_0^\infty t^m e^{-t^2-\frac xt}dt,m\in\Bbb N$$

Special cases:

$$\text f_m(0)=\int_0^\infty t^m e^{-t^2}dt =\frac12 \Gamma\left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right),\text{Re}(m)>-1$$

The great result by Wolfram Alpha using the [Meijer-G function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function):

$$\text f_0(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2-\frac xt}dt=\frac{x\,\text G^{3,0}_{0,3}\left(\frac{x^2}4\bigg|-\frac12,0,0\right)}{4\sqrt \pi}$$

Which can [simplify into an expression with $\,_0\text F_2$ hypergeometric functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/MeijerG/03/01/05/01/)

Here is an attempt at an evaluation. There seems to be no [Polynomial function](https://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/) generating function to make it simpler, so let’s use a regular series expansion integrated with the [Gauss Hypergeometric function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/):

$$\text f_m(x)=\int_0^\infty t^m e^{-t^2-\frac xt}dt=\int_0^\infty t^m\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (t^2+x t^{-1})^n}{n!}dt= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nt^{m-n+1}}{n!(m-n+1)} \,_2\text F_1\left(\frac{m-n+1}3,-n;\frac{m-n+4}3;-\frac{t^3}x\right)\bigg|_0^\infty$$

Where the Gauss Hypergeometric function is just an [Incomplete beta function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Beta3/06/01/), but the  limits make the hypergeometric function diverge. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Note that an equivalent problem is solving it’s recurrence relation also found on NIST:

$$\text f_m(x)\mathop=^{m\ge 2}\frac{m-1}2\text f_{m-2}(x)+\frac x2 \text f_{m-3}(x)$$

also a paper called [“ Evaluation of Abramowitz functions in the right half of the complex plane”](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.12023.pdf) states that a linear partial differential equation for the function is:

$$x\frac {d^3}{dx^3}\text  f_m(x)+(1-m)\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\text f_m(x)+2\text f_m(x)=0 \implies \text f_m(x)=\frac12 c_2(m)x\,_0\text F_2\left(\frac32,1-\frac m2;-\frac{x^2}4\right)+c_1(m) \,_0\text F_2\left(\frac12,\frac{1-m}2;-\frac{x^2}4\right) +\left(\frac x2\right)^{m+1}c_3(m)\,_0\text F_2\left(\frac m2+1,\frac{m+3}2;-\frac{x^2}4\right)$$

and the very simple [delay differential equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation):

$$x\frac{d\,\text f_m(x)}{dx}=-\text f_{m-1}(x)$$

**New Question**

It has been figured out by @Gary and Claude Leibovici, partly from a CAS, that we have a new decomposition formula for $\,_0\text F_2$:

$$\boxed{\text f_m(x>0)=\frac12\Gamma\left(\frac{m+1}2\right)\,_0\text F_2\left(\frac12,\frac{1-m}2;-\frac{x^2}4\right)-\frac x2\Gamma\left(\frac m2\right) \,_0\text F_2\left(\frac32,1-\frac{m}2;-\frac{x^2}4\right)+x^{m+1}\Gamma(-m-1) \,_0\text F_2\left(\frac m2+1,\frac{m+3}2;-\frac{x^2}4\right)} $$

*How does one get this solution from $xy’’’+(1-m)y’’+2y=0,y=y(x)$?* One idea is a power series where the coefficients are a hypergeometric series. I know the question has changes, but this is a question, so a new one is here.

Comment: The asymptotics for large positive $x$ is $$
\mathrm{f}_m (x) \sim \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{3}} \left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right)^{m/3} e^{ - 3(x/2)^{2/3} } .
$$ Use http://dlmf.nist.gov/16.11.E9 for the ${}_0 F_2$ functions and see if it gives you any of the $c_n(m)$s. Then you may compare the values at $x=0$ as well and see what you get for the $c_n(m)$s in that way.

Comment: Provided $x>0$, a CAS gives
$$2\,f_m(x)=-x \Gamma \left(\frac{m}{2}\right) \,
   _0F_2\left(;\frac{3}{2},\frac{2-m}{2};-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)+\Gamma
   \left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right) \,
   _0F_2\left(;\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-m}{2};-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)+$$ $$2 x^{m+1}
   \Gamma (-m-1) \,
   _0F_2\left(;\frac{m+2}{2},\frac{m+3}{2};-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)$$